# Curves and Surfaces

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $$S=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=1\}$$ and                $$T=\left\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \frac{(z+1)^2}{4}=x^2+y^2, z \geq-1 \right\}.$$

(1) Find the $z$-coordinates of the points of intersection of $S$ and $T$ and sketch the projection into the $xy$-plane of the curves of intersection.

I tried to solve simultaneously and found that $z=1/5, 1$. Not sure if this is correct. Also am unsure about the sketch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 pictures of the intersection:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are correct with the $z=1/5,1$. Notice that taking $z$ to be constant in either $S$ or $T$ results in an equation of the form
$$x^2+y^2=\text{const}. $$
Can you recognize what this looks like in the $xy$-plane?

Comment: A circle centered at the origin. I made the mistake of assuming z must equal 0 to sketch in the xy-plane. It makes sensw now :)

Comment: What would the intercepts be?

Comment: @Stuart-JamesBurney That is something you can figure out by substituting the $z$ values you've obtained earlier.

Comment: Ahhh i see. Thank you!!